# Why is ReLU used in regression with Neural Networks?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, keras, regression, activation-function

I am following the official TensorFlow with Keras tutorial and I got stuck here: [Predict house prices: regression - Create the model](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/basic_regression#create_the_model)

Why is an activation function used for a task where a continuous value is predicted?

The code is:

```python
def build_model():
    model = keras.Sequential([
        keras.layers.Dense(64, activation=tf.nn.relu, 
                   input_shape=(train_data.shape[1],)),
        keras.layers.Dense(64, activation=tf.nn.relu),
        keras.layers.Dense(1)
    ])

    optimizer = tf.train.RMSPropOptimizer(0.001)

    model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['mae'])
    return model
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The general reason for using non-linear activation functions in **hidden** layers is that, without them, no matter how many layers or how many units per layer, the network would behave just like a simple linear unit. This is nicely explained in this short video by Andrew Ng: [Why do you need non-linear activation functions?](https://www.coursera.org/lecture/neural-networks-deep-learning/why-do-you-need-non-linear-activation-functions-OASKH)

In your case, looking more closely, you'll see that the activation function of your **final** layer is not the `relu` as in your hidden layers, but the linear one (which is the default activation when you don't specify anything, like here):

```python
keras.layers.Dense(1)
```

From the [Keras docs](https://keras.io/layers/core/#dense):

> **Dense**
>
> [...]
>
> **Arguments**
>
> [...]
>
> **activation**: Activation function to use (see [activations](https://keras.io/activations/)). If you don't specify anything, no activation is applied (ie. "linear" activation: `a(x) = x`).

which is indeed what is expected for a regression network with a single continuous output.

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to answer my question, that was a great video!